# Making Sense of Time Series Data with > 43,000 observations

Tags: r, time-series

**Updated Post**

After a lot of work, I have finally merged three different datasets. The result is a time series data frame with 43,396 observations of 7 seven variables. Below, I have included a few rows of what my data looks like.

```
     Dyad  year  cyberattack  cybersev MID   MIDsev   peace score
     2360  2005    NA          NA       0      1          0
     2360  2006    NA          NA       NA     NA         0
     2360  2007    1           3.0      0      1          0
     2360  2008    1           4.0      0      1          0
     2360  2009    3           3.33     1      4          0
     2360  2010    1           3.0      NA     NA         0
     2360  2011    3           2.0      NA     NA         0
     2360  2012    1           2.0      NA     NA         0 
     2360  2013    4           2.0      NA     NA         0
```

If I am interested in comparing how different country pairs (dyads) differ in how often they launch attacks (either in cyberspace, physically with MIDs, or neither)...how should I go about doing this?

Since I am working with country/year data, how can I get descriptive statistics for the different countries (Dyads) in my Dyad variable? For example, I would like to know how the behavior of Dyad 2360 (USA and Iran) compares with other countries.

I tried this code, but it just gave me a list of my unique dyad pairs:

```
    table(final$Dyadpair) 
    names(sort(-table(final$Dyadpair)))
```

You mentioned using **aggregate** or **dplyr** - but I don't see how those will allow me to descriptive statistics for all of my unique dyads? Would you mind elaborating on this?

Is it possible for a code to return something like this: For Dyad 2360 during the years 2005-2013, 80% were NA, 10% were cyber attacks, and 10% were MID attacks, etc. ?

---

**Upate to clarify:**

Ok, yes - the above example was just hypothetical. Based on the nine rows of data that I have provided - here is what I am hoping R can provide when it comes to descriptive statistics.

**Dyad**: 2360
No attacks: 22.22% (2/9) ….in 2005 and 2006

**Cyber attacks**: 77.78% (7/9) ….in  the years 2007-2013

**MID attacks**: 11.11% (1/9) ….in 2009

**Both cyber and MID**: 11.11% (1/9) ….in 2009

Essentially, during a given time range (2005-2013 for the example I gave above), how many of those years result in NO attacks, how many of those years result in a cyber attack, how many of those years result in a MID attack, and how many of those years result in both a cyber and MID attack.

I do not know if this is possible with how my data is set up —> since I aggregated cyber-attacks and MID attacks per year? And yes, I would also like to take into consideration the severity of the attacks (both cyber attacks and MID attacks), but I don’t know how to do that.

Does this help clarify what I am looking for?

Comment: When you `merge`, you can set the argument `all = TRUE` to keep all records. For the rest, "how to make sense of my data so that it comes across in a paper and presentation" is far too broad. Stack Overflow is for specific, answerable, programming questions---that is a general, open-ended question about data analysis and communication.

Comment: Some general advice - you've identified some weaknesses, like inconsistent use of `NA`, different rating scales, etc. Whether and how much those will cause problems will depend on how you analyze them, but consistency is good and will generally make things better. I would advise (a) using `NA` consistently for missing values, rather than for 0s, (b) using consistent scales--`1` makes sense to me as a non-severe attack, `0` as no attack, and `NA` as "we don't know". Transforming your data to do (a) and (b) is probably a good idea. And do so *before* you aggregate and take averages.

Comment: As to getting descriptive statistics for unique dyads, in base R `aggregate`, which you're already using, is a good tool for that. You'll have to define what you mean exactly by "the percentage of the time they launch cyber attacks" - maybe you mean *the percentage of all attacks that are cyber attacks*, or maybe you mean *the percentage of years with attacks that include cyber attacks*, or maybe you mean something else. While `aggregate` is good in base R, you may find `dplyr` more powerful, [here's a nice introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html).

Comment: Hello, @Gregor. Thank you for your feedback. I have updated my post with a more specific question.

Comment: @Gregor Also, adding the "all = TRUE" to my merge code, worked. Thank you. I would most appreciate if you could take a look at my updated post.

Comment: Please help me understand the definitions of the summary statistics you want. What are the actual values you want? *"For Dyad 2360 during the years 2005-2013, 80% were NA, 10% were cyber attacks, and 10% were MID attacks, etc"* doesn't make sense with the sample data you show--as far as I can tell.

Comment: For Dyad 2360 during the years 2005-2013, I see 9 rows each of `cyberAttack` and `MID`, 7 NA values total. Do you want to report 7/18 = 38.9% NAs? Or do you want add up the values when there are  not NAs? I think they all add up to 15, so 7/15 = 46.7% NAs? What about the percentage of Mids - how to count the 0s? Does severity matter for these summaries? Explain the exact logic you want to use, and I can help you use it. Concrete examples using the sample data are nice and easy to understand.

Comment: @Gregor I apologize for the confusion. I added to my post with some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` approach with my best guess for what you want. It will output a data frame with one row per dyad and the same summary statistics for each dyad.

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(Dyad) %>%
  summarize(
    year_range = paste(min(year), max(year), sep = "-"),
    no_attacks = mean(is.na(cyberattack) & (is.na(MID) | MID == 0)),
    cyber_attacks = mean(!is.na(cyberattack)),
    MID_attacks = mean(!is.na(MID) & MID > 0),
    cyber_and_MID = mean(!is.na(cyberattack) & (!is.na(MID) & MID > 0)),
    cyber_sev_weighted = weighted.mean(cyberattack, w = cybersev, na.rm = TRUE)
  )

# # A tibble: 1 x 7
#    Dyad year_range no_attacks cyber_attacks MID_attacks cyber_and_MID cyber_sev_weighted
#   <int> <chr>           <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>              <dbl>
# 1  2360 2005-2013       0.222         0.778       0.111         0.111               1.86
```

---

Using this data:

```
your_data = read.table(text = 'Dyad  year  cyberattack  cybersev MID   MIDsev   peace_score
     2360  2005    NA          NA       0      1          0
     2360  2006    NA          NA       NA     NA         0
     2360  2007    1           3.0      0      1          0
     2360  2008    1           4.0      0      1          0
     2360  2009    3           3.33     1      4          0
     2360  2010    1           3.0      NA     NA         0
     2360  2011    3           2.0      NA     NA         0
     2360  2012    1           2.0      NA     NA         0 
     2360  2013    4           2.0      NA     NA         0', header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. The only thing that I am still confused about is the weighed cyber severity variable? In my data, "cybersev" (cyber attack severity) and "MIDsev" (MID attack severity) represent the mean severity of attacks for a given year. So, I'm not quite sure how to represent this if I am trying to collapse an age range like I did for the two attacks variables. I tried adding this code: `cyber_severity = mean(!is.na(cybersev)), MID_severity = mean(!is.na(MIDsev)),` to the code you provided, but that returned a number that didn't really make sense?

Comment: Break it into pieces to understand. `is.na(cybersev)` is TRUE (1) when cybersev is NA, and FALSE (0) otherwise. `!` makes that opposite. `mean` takes the mean of those numbers, so `mean(!is.na(cybersev))` is like `cyber_attacks = mean(!is.na(cyberattack))`, it will give you the proportion of rows (years) that have a non-missing value for `cyberattack`. Probably more useful is `mean(cybersev, na.rm = TRUE)`, which will average the `cybersev` values, ignoring (removing) the NAs.

Comment: Yes. That worked. Thank you. I followed the same logic for MID severity, and that also worked. The only thing that is not ideal is that when I ran this code: `year_range = paste(min(1992), max(2016), sep = "-")` --  because those are the total years that my three merged datasets cover... that resulted in the descriptives statistics data frame labeling each dyad as "1992-2016," when more often than not, the years covered for each specific dyad are not that large due to missingness (NAs). Is there a way that R can automatically detect the years covered by a Dyad?

Comment: For example, a dyad might only interact with each other during the years 1998-2007. But according to the data frame, it looks as though attacks occur during the year range 1992-2016. Does that question make sense?

Comment: Sure, filter your data frame so that those useless rows aren't there. Maybe you want to filter out rows where all of your measure columns are either `0` or `NA`. Create a little help function for testing if something is not NA or 0 - `present = function(x) !is.na(x) & x > 0`, then `your_data %>% filter(present(cyberatttack) | present(cybersev) | present(MID) | present(MIDsev))` to keep rows where at least one of the columns has a non-missing, greather than 0 value.